# Error C2280 (Referencing deleted function) while trying to populate std::vector

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I am working on a simple dungeon crawler using C++. To manage the enemies I created an `std::vector` of my class "Enemy", but when I tried to `push_back`the newly created instances, Visual Studio complained that I was referencing the deleted function `Enemy::Enemy(const Enemy&)`. 
So far so good. After some intense googling I found out that Visual Studio apparently implicitly overrides the generated copy constructor and deletes it. In one answer somebody explained that I have to set the copy constructor to defaul ( `Enemy::Enemy(const Enemy&) = default`), this however did not solve the problem. 
Another solution was using the move constructor to not copy the instance with `push_back(enemy)` but to move it using `push_back(std::move(enemy))`. This resulted in the instance not being initialized properly...

I'm now completely clueless why this happens and would be really glad if somebody could explain me why these errors keep occuring and how to fix them.

main.cpp:

```
std::vector<Enemy> enemies;
int reservedSpace = rndDeco(eng); //how many enemies will be spawned
enemies.reserve(reservedSpace);

for (int i = 0; i < reservedSpace; i++ ) {
    Enemy x(&monsters[rnd(eng)], sf::Vector2u(5, 4), 0.2f, 100.0f, 110, 10);
    enemies.push_back(std::move(x)); //pushing back an uninitialized enemy
}
```

Enemy.h

```
class Enemy
{
public:
 Enemy(sf::Texture* texture, sf::Vector2u imageCount, float switchTime, float speed,
    int baseHealth, int baseStrength);

 Enemy(const Enemy&) = default;

 Enemy(Enemy&&) noexcept {} //deleting this and just pushing back results in a C2280
//however using it and  std:: move to move the instance to the vector 
//results in an uninitialized instance

 Enemy();

 ~Enemy();

... (other functions which are not important)

public:
 int direction;
 int counter;
 bool isVisible;
 bool dead = false;
 bool attacks = false;
 int timer = 0;
 int strength;


private:

 RandomOperations rndOp;
 sf::RectangleShape body;
 Animation animation;
 unsigned int row;
 float speed;
 bool faceRight;
 int health;
};
```

If I missed a part of code which is important, just let me know and I'll add it.

I hope you can help me and sorry if this is a stupid question, but I looked through all the other questions related to C2280 and couldn't find an answer which helped me.

**EDIT: Solved it with the help of tobi303**

Comment: what error do you get after adding `Enemy(const Enemy&) = default;` ?

Comment: Are all your class members copyable?  If not they will make your defaulted copy constructor deleted.

Comment: Also, `Enemy(Enemy&&) noexcept {}` does nothing, which you see.  You need `Enemy(Enemy&&)  = default;` like the copy constructor.

Comment: @tobi303 I still get the C2280 error, which is the main reason I tried to resort to moving instead of copying.

Comment: @NathanOliver I'll try that one

Comment: does the class have any members that you do not show here? e.g. a reference would be problematic

Comment: are the members that you show here copyable? e.g. `RandomOperations`, `Animations`  ?

Comment: Back from testing: @NathanOliver it just throws C2280 again when using `Enemy(Enemy&&) = default`

Comment: Please create a [mcve].

Comment: @tobi303 No, the class does not have any other members. Not sure about the second question though. I just started reading into constructors and all that. How would I determine whether a member is copyable?

Comment: either you check their declaration or simply try to push some instances to a vector

Comment: @tobi303 Sometimes I am astonished on how I can forget the simplest things such as pushing it back to test if it's copyable... Anyways, RandomOperations seems to be the problem as it throws the exact same error. Shall I add its code to the original question for you to have a look at?

Comment: @T.N. errm no your code is already too non-minimal. Now that you found the source of the problem you have to see what you can do with that `RandomOperations`. Can you make it copyable in any meaningful way? As a workaround you could use a `vector<unique_ptr<Enemy>>`, just note that `unique_ptr` also cannot be copied (but moved)

Comment: @tobi303 Alright, thank you. I just found that I used std::random_device in RandomOperations, which isn't copyable (for obvious reasons).

Comment: instead of your last edit, I would suggest you to remove some of the irrelevant code, e.g. all what you have in the .cpp doesnt matter for copying